# How to show that function $G=xy-\frac{x^a}{a}-\frac{y^b}{b}<0$ where $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}\neq 0$ or $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} \neq 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For function $G = xy - \frac{x^a}{a} - \frac{y^b}{b}$, $x,y \geq 0 $ and $a > 1$, $b > 1$, $ a - 1 = \frac{1}{b-1}$ how to prove that $G(x,y) < 0$ for $(x,y) \notin  U =\{ (x,y) |  \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = 0 \} $. Due to given conditions $U$ is set of points where $y = x^{a-1}$. Can you give some ideas how $G(x,y) < 0:(x,y) \notin  U$ can be shown?

Comment: Surely your class has discussed finding critical points and maxima and minima.

Comment: You suggest to find maximum of the function at the points beyond $U$ and show that this maximum is below zero? The question what I should differentiate then... I mean how I could differentiate the function where $ (x,y) \notin U \Leftrightarrow y \neq x^{a-1}$

Comment: $G$ is easily differentiated everywhere. I don't understand what your concern is there. Do you know the maximum principle? That is, that if a function has non-zero derivative everywhere in the interior of a bounded domain, and is continuous on the boundary of the domain, then the maximum and minimum values of the function occur on the boundary?